# AES Encryption and Decryption by the Chunk was resulting wrong output

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

Hi i am using c# code and trying to encrypt and decrypt a CSV file
which is having lacks of record and 24 columns.

Encypting it by 4 mb chunk by chunk and generated the salt by random. How do i fix this issue.

encrypting the csv files chunk by chunk and decypting it back.I was getting wrong result in the resulting csv. some junk chars were getting after each chunk.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You write the salt one time at the beginning of the stream, but read it for each chunk.

Change your encrpt method like this:

```
....
MemoryStream mstream = null;

try {

    while ((bytesRead = Infs.Read(chunk, 0, chunkSizeInBytes)) > 0) {
        mstream = new MemoryStream();
        mstream.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(mstream, aesProvider.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
....
```

or remove the `fsCrypt.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);` inside the while loop of the Decrypt method.

Comment: After removing the line fsCrypt.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length)  also same issue

Comment: That is strange. I tested it with a generated file `using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Check.csv")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024; i++) {
                        writer.WriteLine("12345678");
                    }
                }` and after Encrypt and Decrypt the files are identical.